# Searching and adding product in cart of bigbasket using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I was trying to search and add product in the cart using selenium but was not able to successfully do it

```
  driver.get("https://www.bigbasket.com/cl/fruits-vegetables/?nc=nb");
  List<WebElement> product = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@qa=\'product\']"));
    System.out.println("prdoduct=" + product.size());
    for(int i=0;i<product.size();i++)
    {
        String name = product.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println("NAME is" + name);

        String  xp= "(//button[@qa=\'add\'])" + "["+i+ "]";
        System.out.println("xp="+xp);
        if(name.contains("Cauliflower"))
        {
            System.out.println("xp" +xp);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(xp)).click();     
         }
     }
```

In this previous product is getting selected but when I was debugging it was on the cauliflower     but still the previous product is getting selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a chance that some time the element get overlapped by another element. At this time, the normal selenium click will try to click on the overlapped element. so it is better to use js click, it will click the exact element even if it is overlapped

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath(xp));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

There is also a chance for issue in your xpath. Since list starts at 0 , you may need to change i in to i+1 in xp for getting current selection add button.do try this xpath too

```
String  xp= "(//button[@qa=\'add\'])" + "["+(i+1)+ "]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy`() and use following `css selector` and `xpath`.

```
driver.get("https://www.bigbasket.com/cl/fruits-vegetables/?nc=nb"); 
List<WebElement> product =new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div[qa='product_name']>a")));
System.out.println("prdoduct=" + product.size());
   for(int i=0;i<product.size();i++)
        {
            String name = product.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println("NAME is" + name);

            if(name.contains("Cauliflower"))
            {                
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@qa='product_name']//a[text()='" + name + "']/following::button[1]")).click();     
             }
         }
```